# How can solve the Ros installation error on Ubuntu

Tags: vmware, ubuntu-18.04, ros

I am trying to install ros-melodic-desktop-full on Ubuntu 18.04 on Vmware but i get this error:
E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-desktop-full
what is worng?

Answer (score 1):

Before install ros-melodic-desktop-full, try this commands

```
$sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'

$sudo apt-key adv --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80' --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654

$sudo apt update
```

and then, install melodic using command below

```
$sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop-full
```

Comment: thank you for answering, i did what you said but  it still has the same error:                  Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-desktop-full

Answer (score 0):

you have to set up your system to accept packages from packages.ros.org.
adding keys and

**set up your source list**

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

**set up your system keys**

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80' --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654
```

or

```
curl -sSL 'http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0xC1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654' | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt update
```

or follow this link

[ROS INSTALLATION GUIDE](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu)

if you still face problem try follow this [ROS INSTALLATION](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment)

Answer (score 0):

follow ROS Installation guidelines[Installing and Configuring Your ROS Environment](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment)